# How to use Gmail API with firebase login in an angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am trying to create an angular app that will access a user's emails. I have setup logging in through an angular component using firebase. I also have an Express backend using the Gmail api that logs in and stores the access and refresh token locally. I'm not sure how to set this up for multiple users. I can write to a firestore database, but I'm not sure if I should store the refresh token there. I also feel like I have login logic duplicated in the angular component and the express backend. What is the correct way to set this up?

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  auth: AngularFireAuth;

  constructor(fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.auth = fireAuth;
   }

   login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("../../serviceAccountKey.json");   // make environment variable

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "database"   // actual url to the database in my code
});

let db = admin.firestore();

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions

      let docRef = db.collection('users').doc('me'); // can't access current user here

      // Should I be adding the token to the database here?

      let tokenSetQuery = docRef.set({
        first: 'Test',
        last: 'Lovelace',
        born: 1815,
        token: token
      });

      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.messages.list({
    userId: 'me'
  }, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const labels = res.data.messages;
    console.log(res)
    if (labels.length) {
      console.log('Labels:');
      labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.id}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    }
  });
}


/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('api works');
});


router.get('/testing', (req, res) => {

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's the problem with storing the refresh tokens in firebase?

Comment: There isn't a problem but I wasn't sure if this was the correct way to do this. I have never implemented an auth system like this and didn't know if I should be using a google api to directly get a new refresh token, or if I should store it in firebase and query it every time a user logs in. My main issue with doing that though is I do not have access to the current user in the api.js file, so I don't know how I would access the specific refresh token that I need.